# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, forms, exception, laravel, request

I am currently creating a website that, once the user arrives, they are greeted by a form with which they input their unique id and DoB.  Upon entering the information and clicking submit, they are sent to the main form which has only a little information on it and the user must enter the rest.  My problem arises when I try to submit the form as I keep getting the following error:

```
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST', 'PATCH'))
```

Note: I do not want any variables in my routes.  (ex: I want 'form/person' and not 'form/{person_id}').  Also, I have included only the relavent information regarding the errors.

gate.blade.php - (this is where the user enters their ID and date of birth):

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'JurorsController@form', 'class' => 'form-inline')) !!}
```

form.blade.php - (this is the primary form the user must fill out and submit):

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => action('JurorsController@submit'), 'method' => 'PATCH', 'class' => 'form-inline']) !!}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::patch('jurors/form', 'JurorsController@submit');
Route::get('jurors', 'JurorsController@gate');
Route::post('jurors/form', 'JurorsController@form');
```

JurorController@submit

```
public function submit(FormSubmitRequest $request)
{
    //never reaches this point nor executes submit... instead redirects to gate IF it doesn't return 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException' error.
    dd($request);
}
```

The only time I managed to get it to not show me the 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException' exception, I instead got redirected to the gate.blade.php page.  If you have any questions for me or need me to clerify on anything, leave me a comment and I will respond once I am able to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me your problem is the url in our routes. You are repeating them.

Firstly I would recommend using named routes as it will give you a bit more definition between routes. I'd change your routes to

```
Route::put('jurors/submit',[
    'as' => 'jurors.submit',
    'uses' => 'JurorsController@submit'
]);

Route::get('jurors',[
    'as' => 'jurors.gate',
    'uses' => 'JurorsController@gate'
]);

Route::post('jurors/form', [
    'as' => 'jurors.form',
    'uses' => 'JurorsController@form'
]);
```

Also on your submit route why are you using a PATCH request. wouldn't you use a POST request with all the data in? If you do still need to use Patch then you should be using `put` instead in your routes. 
Another way for for testing and debugging you could use `any` to see if it is your HTTP request which is causing the error for example

```
Route::any('jurors/submit',[
        'as' => 'jurors.submit',
        'uses' => 'JurorsController@submit'
    ]);
```

Also then you can use the name of your route in your `form::open()` for example

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'jurors.form', 'class' => 'form-inline')) !!}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome, I shall give it a try on Monday when I have access to the project.  I need to read up on what PATCH is exactly as it's apparently not what I thought it was.

Comment: I found the main source of my problems wasn't even related to the routes, but rather, the form rules.  Regardless, I have set the method to put for now and using the exact same route path as the form itself (post = put = 'jurors/form').

Comment: I have finally found the source of the problem: it is the fact that I am posting twice in a row.  What I mean by this is that the gate is a post request and the form after is also a form request.  Attempting to use any $request rules to apply to the fields results in the methodnotallowedhttpexception.